# Assistance with duplication values in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formatting, formula

I've got an excel sheet here where I'm trying to see if I need to apply a user license, device license, or none, and this is based on whether or not there are duplicates within a column.  For example, if there's a unique entry in column A, the corresponding entry in column B should read "device".  What complicates things though would be the "user licenses" where a "User license" would function for 5 accounts, and everyone after the 5th license would also be counted as a device.  Any ideas for a formula that could help me get through 22k lines of this mess?

```
A   User
A   N/A
A   N/A
B   User
B   N/A
B   N/A
B   N/A
B   N/A
B   Device
B   Device
B   Device
B   Device
C   Device
```

Comment: I was exploring things along the lines of IF statements, but I haven't really nailed anything down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>5),"Device",IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,"User","N/A"))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a beautiful human being and I'm renaming my daughter Scott....not really....but let's pretend I did huh?

Comment: @GilAraujo I will settle for you marking it as complete by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sounds great I'll do that! As a bonus could you break down what's going on in this formula?  Better yet is there somewhere I can go where I can enter complex formulas like this and it breaks down what's happening?  I'm trying to learn more.

Comment: you can just use the evaluate option on the formula tab.  But it is just counting things.  The `A:A` looks at the whole column, I use this to see how many total there are to see if it is unique.  The `$A$1:A1` is a dynamic range.  The end changed to the row in which the formula is, so it is always looking at the range above it.  I use this to know if it is the first or greater than the 5.  Then just some OR logic and a nested IF to get the correct returns.